# Remove underline from paginator makes problem with other input (Angular material)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I Customize my paginator and remove the underline from it

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

How i do it?

I wrote this in my style.sass

```
.mat-form-field-underline
  display: none
```

The problem is that i have in other components "mat-form-field" and it delete him the underline from all inputs.

There is a way to add a custom class to the paginator? what the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-paginator .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```